# Программа переносит часть текста на новую строку если число символов превышает допустимое значение

Tags: c++

Программа переносит часть текста на новую строку если число символов превышает допустимое значение в строке.

Алгоритм программы:
 1. Есть текст. *Привеет Как Дела*

2. Вводим количество допустимых символов на одну строку, я ввожу n = 4.
3. Программа с помощью цикла for выберает первые n символов и их помещает в новый тип string и ищет среди них возможность выполнения условия деления: две идущие подряд гласные можно разделить, если перед первой из них стоит согласная, а за второй идет хотя бы одна буква (буква й при этом рассматривается вместе с предшествующей ей гласной как единое целое). Если нет такой возможности, то программа прекращает роботу.

   У меня возникла проблема после цикла for где я хочу поместить первые n символов в новый тип string, компилятор компилирует прогу, но когда дело доходит до участка кода прога вылетает: `cout << clone.insert(str.find(str[nom]), str);`

Сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

void delitel(string str, int i, int n);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    vector<string> arr;
    string str("Привеет Как Дела");
    string delim(" ");
    size_t prev = 0;
    size_t next;
    size_t delta = delim.length();
    int i;
    cout << "Введи количество символов в строке: ";
    cin >> i;

    while ((next = str.find(delim, prev)) != string::npos) 
    {
        //Отладка-start
        string tmp = str.substr(prev, next - prev);
        cout << tmp << " ";
        //Отладка-end
        arr.push_back(str.substr(prev, next - prev));
        prev = next + delta;
    }
    //Отладка-start
    string tmp = str.substr(prev);
    cout << tmp << endl;
    //Отладка-end
    arr.push_back(str.substr(prev));
    cout << endl;

    int n;
    n = str.size();
    if (n > i)
        delitel(str, i, n);
    system("pause");
}

void delitel(string str, int i, int n)
{
    int nom;
    string clone;
    for (nom = 0; nom <= i; nom++)
    {
        cout << str[nom];
    }
    cout << clone.insert(str.find(str[nom]), str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Объект `clone` не содержит данных, или, по-другому, содержит пустую строку.

Вызов метода `find` для строки `str` (`str.find(str[nom])`) в любом случае вернет значение отличное от 0. Поэтому вызов метода `insert` для строки `clone`

```
cout << clone.insert(str.find(str[nom]), str);
```

приведет к возникновению исключения, так как заданная позиция вставки больше размера (пустой) строки, содержащейся в объекте `clone`.

Comment: void delitel(string str, int i, int n)
{
 int nom;
 vector< string > text;
 for (nom = 0; nom <= i; nom++)
 {
  text.push_back(str);
 }

 cout << text[i];
}

Почему выводится весь текст, если должно вывести первые 4 символы, при і=4.

Comment: @nicolia А в этом предложении text.push_back( str );  вы разве занесли в вектор не всю строку?